# when ever i change single line of css should i have to deploy static content all time

Tags: magento2

I was working with magento 2 and trying to change some css whenever i change single line of css forexample i was trying to change the _module.less file in Magento_Theme/web/css/source 
whenever i change sinle line of it didnt show any change but when i remove content from pub/static folder and var/cache and var/view_preprocessed then i am able to see the change what could be the better solution for it to save time ?
I am in a developer mode .

Answer (score 0):

If you are in developer mode, you should be able to just refresh the page. Personally, I use grunt and livereload. However, if you are not using those, I find it helpful to do the following when I first start:

1. rm -rf pub/static/frontend
2. rm -rf var/cache
3. rm -rf var/page_cache
4. rm -rf var/view_preprocessed
5. php bin/magento cache:disable full_page block_html
6. php bin/magento cache:clean
7. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area=frontend (this isn't truly necessary but I always do this when I begin the task and NOT on each change)

Also, if you still don't see the changes, flush your browser cache.

Comment: I am in a developer mode i am unable to see changes when i refresh the page ... to see the change i have to do the steps you have mentioned again and again .

Comment: I just updated my answer. Try to follow it exactly, step by step and see what happens

Comment: no you dont understand my question when i remove the folders you have mentioned  and deploy static content i see the changes but for every change i have to do this , i dont want to to do this .... i have tried your answer

Answer (score 0):

If your are editing `less` files you need to follow the steps mentioned on other answers. Or configure grunt task runners to compile the less once a file is changed.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

Answer (score 0):

Always Use developer mode when you are making changes to website.

For me, after making CSS/JS changes, i need to clear magento  cache by running

> php bin/magento cache:clean

and then clear Browser cache (Ctrl+Shift+Delete and Clear cache)

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing in less file and want reflection of your changes withour removing static content, you should use client side compilation instead of server side compilation. Check this for more information:https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html